# delay on_trait_change() when cycling through values - only execute when mouse is unclicked

Tags: enthought

If you have a Range trait setup how do you make it only carry out the change once the user has stopped moving through the range?

ie. some range is changed:

```
some_trait_changed(self):
    wait for user to finish selection
    complex calculation.
```

Every time the user drags the Range tool, it calculates a new value for every single value in the range. I only want it to run once they have settled on a value... i.e. once the mouse has 'unclicked'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Range(..., auto_set=False)`. The `auto_set` keyword gets passed to the `RangeEditor` which will configure the slider appropriately.

Comment: Thank-you sir! Everything is as it should be.